# Boost regex for parsing key/value pairs from a string

Tags: regex, boost, key-value

I have the following string for which I am trying to parse the key value pairs:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string deliveryReceipt = "id:pgl01130529155035239084 sub:001 dlvrd:001 submit date:1305291550 done date:1305291550 stat:DELIVRD err:0";

    std::map<std::string, std::string> results;
    boost::regex re("(?:([^:]+):([^,]+)(?:,|$))+"); // key - value pair

    boost::sregex_iterator it(deliveryReceipt.begin(), deliveryReceipt.end(), re), end;
    for ( ; it != end; ++it){
      results[(*it)[1]] = (*it)[2];
    }    

    std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator resultsIter = results.begin();
    while (resultsIter != results.end())
    {
        std::cout << "key:" << resultsIter->first << " value:" << resultsIter->second << std::endl;
        resultsIter++;
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

key:id value:pgl01130529155035239084 sub:001 dlvrd:001 submit date:1305291550 done date:1305291550 stat:DELIVRD err:0

How to fix this regex for parsing key/value pairs properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with something like this (***updated***)

`"\\s*(?<!\\S)([^:]+)\\s*:(\\S+)(?!\\S)"`

https://regex101.com/r/Sufx5m/1

Explained

```
 \s*              # Optional whitespace trim
 (?<! \S)         # Whitespace boundary delimiter
                  #   (also matches at beginning of string)
 ( [^:]+ )        # (1), Key - not any ':' colon chars
 \s*              # Optional whitespace trim
 :                # Colon 
 ( \S+ )          # (2), Value - not whitespace chars
 (?! \S )         # Whitespace boundary delimiter.
                  #   (also matches at end of string)
```

Answer (score 2):

Modern C++ allows for much better things than putrid regexes.

You can write a strong-typed grammar specification in a a few lines of code using Boost Spirit:

```
using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
auto key   = lexeme [ +(char_ - ':') ];
auto value = lexeme [ +graph ];
auto kvp   = lexeme [key >> ':' >> value];
return skip(space) [ *kvp ];
```

## Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/986d721fae829d4f)</kbd>**

```
#include <map>
// for debug output only
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

// for parsing
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

static inline auto kvp_parser() {
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
    auto key   = lexeme [ +(char_ - ':') ];
    auto value = lexeme [ +graph ];
    auto kvp   = lexeme [key >> ':' >> value];
    return skip(space) [ *kvp ];
}

int main() {
    std::string const deliveryReceipt = "id:pgl01130529155035239084 sub:001 dlvrd:001 submit date:1305291550 done date:1305291550 stat:DELIVRD err:0";

    std::map<std::string, std::string> results;

    parse(begin(deliveryReceipt), end(deliveryReceipt), kvp_parser(), results);

    for (auto& [k,v]: results) {
        std::cout << "key:" << std::quoted(k) << "\tvalue:" << std::quoted(v) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
key:"dlvrd" value:"001"
key:"done date" value:"1305291550"
key:"err"   value:"0"
key:"id"    value:"pgl01130529155035239084"
key:"stat"  value:"DELIVRD"
key:"sub"   value:"001"
key:"submit date"   value:"1305291550"
```

Answer (score 1):

This expression,

```
(?<=^|\s)([^:]+):(\S*)(?=$|\s)
```

or

```
(?<=^|\s)([^:]+):(\S*)
```

might be OK to start with, and you can modify for language-based escapings.

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/uOMY2v/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/uOMY2v/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 1):

If the delimiter is `:` and the keys and values itself do not contain `:` you might use:

```
\s*([^:]+):([^:\s]+)
```

In parts

- `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace chars
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[^:]+` Match any char except `:` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
- `)` Close group
- `:` Match literally
- `(` Capture group 2

  - `[^:\s]+` Match any char except `:` or whitespace char
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vIbVEB/1)

Comment: I don't believe you can assume `:` on the value side is not allowed in a continuous non-spaced value, only a space seems not to be allowed.

Comment: @sln That's a valid point. In that case `([^:\s]+)` could become `(\S+)`

Comment: Yeah, uh sort of something this `\s*(?<!\S)([^:]+)\s*:(\S+)(?!\S)`